# Click event is not working in CSS

Tags: asp.net, css

I am not able to get the click evet in CSS

My code is like this

```
<input name="btn" type="button" onclick="~/Default22.aspx" value="Home" class="classname" style="position:absolute; left: 286px; top: 160px; margin-bottom: 0px;"/>
```

and I have class="classname"

```
.classname
 {

    text-indent:1px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#132354;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:32px;
    line-height:50px;
    width:144px;
    padding 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity:.5;
 }
    .classname:hover 
    {
        background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom,color-stop(0.05,      #77d42a), color-stop(5, #5cb811) );
        background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffffff 60%, #c0C0C0 90% );
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient      (startColorstr='#77d42a',endColorstr='#5cb811');
        background-color:#5cb811;
        opacity:1;
 }
  .classname:active 
 {
        position:relative;
        top:1px;
 }
```

The problem is when I click the button click event is not happening..not redirecting the page to Deafault22.aspx

I am working on Asp.net framework
Please help me

Comment: Replace button to submit and try

Comment: Input does not have a on-click event inbuit

Answer (score 2):

An HTML `input` element will not redirect to a web page in the `onclick` attribute, because it does not know how to redirect via that attribute.

Use a server control, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Home" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Redirect here
    Response.Redirect("Default22.aspx);
}
```

Use JavaScript/jQuery to handle the click event and redirect, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.classname').click(function() {
        window.location = "Default22.aspx";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  use `onclick='window.open("Default22.aspx");'`  instead  of `onclick="~/Default22.aspx"`

**Inline Script:**

`onclick='window.location.href ="Default22.aspx";'`

**javascript function**:

```
 function Redirect(){
      window.location.href ="Default22.aspx";
 }

 <input name="btn" type="button" onclick="Redirect();" value="Home" class="classname" style="position:absolute; left: 286px; top: 160px; margin-bottom: 0px;"/>
```

**Jquery:**

```
 $(function() {
     $('.classname').click(function() {
        window.location.href = "Default22.aspx";
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`OnClick` attribute of any HTML control is meant to be used for JavaScript. You have confused it with `HREF` attribute of `<a></a>` element

Here is what you need to do:

```
onclick="window.location.href ='Default2.aspx';return true;"
```

Comment: There's no need to `return true;` if it's not a server control, which his example isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, 'the click event in CSS' - not sure what you're talking about. You can't handle click events in CSS.

Secondly, that's not how the `<input type="button">` works. onClick - the client-side event - is expecting some Javascript, not a URL.

Try this: -

> `onclick="window.location = '/Default22.aspx';"`

Note that the ~ (tilde) is an ASP.NET-specific thing and not relevant to IIS; don't use it in a regular URL.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Direct onclick="~/Default22.aspx" will not work here as this is a input type button, have to add client side events like..

```
onclick="window.location.href ='Default22.aspx';return true;" for opening in the same window.
```

or

```
onclick="window.open('Default22.aspx');", for opening the page in a tab.
```

Also you can created a javascript method and call that method inside the onClick and redirecting the page to Deafault22.aspx.